# && in value javascripit

Tags: javascript

Today i see something like this

```
const a = 1 && 2 && 3 && 4
```

And when we console.log this **it will return 4**

As my understand, i think it will return **true** mean, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 do not consider falsy value, so it will return true, but this make me think about condition

From when i learn javascript, i always read condition like this:

```
if(1 &&2 ) {
   return true
}
```

So i think `1&&2` will return true, apply for above code, why it return 4 ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#using_and

Comment: *'So i think 1&&2 will return true...'* it returns 2. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#description): *'Logical AND (&&) evaluates operands from left to right, returning immediately with the **value** of the first falsy operand it encounters; if all values are truthy, the **value** of the last operand is returned.'*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan simply because it is evaluated as truthy the statement '1&&2 will return true' is still not accurate. It returns 2 which is evaluated by the `if` (not the &&) as a boolean and so found to be truthy.